# How to create a ROS package?

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After creating a ROS package i'm trying the compile a code for a publisher node. I execute the command

rosmake minimal_nodes

The following error appears:

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['minimal_nodes']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/fcs_basestation/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141120-145630
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['minimal_nodes'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['minimal_nodes']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

I know i have to add the package to the ros_package_path. My question is how i do that? I have seen this question a lot of time here with worthless answers to it. I'm using hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197896/how-to-create-a-ros-package?/) by [ed_win33](https://answers.ros.org/users/20879/ed_win33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the package you want to build is a rosbuild package (it has a `manifest.xml` and not a `package.xml`) then you need to put one of its containing folders in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. Imagine you have something like this:

```
% tree /tmp/my_workspace
/tmp/my_workspace
└── my_package
    └── manifest.xml
    └── ...

1 directory, 1 file
```

And you want to build `my_package`, then you should put at least the `my_workspace` folder on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`:

```
$ export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/tmp/my_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

That will allow `rosmake` to find your package and try to build it.

Also you should do that export line after sourcing any other `setup.bash` files, e.g. `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ed_win33](https://answers.ros.org/users/20879/ed_win33/) on 2014-11-21**:
Correct, it has a manifest.xml and not a package.xml.

I run the the command:
$ export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/tmp/my_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
replacing my_workspace with TestcodesRos which is my package and i'm still having the same error.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-21**:
You put the *path* to `TestcodesRos` or just `TestcodesRos`? Please post exactly what you ran.

**Comment by [ed_win33](https://answers.ros.org/users/20879/ed_win33/) on 2014-11-24**:
I ran:

$ export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/tmp/TestcodeRos:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

PD:
My TestcodeRos is created on the desktop.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-24**:
@ed_win33 if `TestcodeRos` is on your Desktop then you have to put the path to it in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`... Something like this `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/YOURUSER/Desktop/TestcodeRos:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. It obviously isn't at `/tmp/TestcodeRos`...

**Comment by [ed_win33](https://answers.ros.org/users/20879/ed_win33/) on 2014-11-25**:
I successfully added the package to the path but when I run rosmake minimal_nodes is still not running. Also if i open a new terminal and run  echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH the package that I just add is not there anymore. I read that this is something to be with the setup.bash.

**Comment by [ed_win33](https://answers.ros.org/users/20879/ed_win33/) on 2014-11-25**:
I tried several thing to fix the sourcing, if this is the problem, but no results by now

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-27**:
You have to add it to the RPP in every new terminal or add it to your `.bashrc`. I would encourage you to read up on Linux terminals and how the shell environment works, the problems you are having are not really ROS related, but are instead related to how shells work in Linux.